# How do I save imported data from R studio so that I can knit?

Tags: r, knitr

My program runs exactly how I want it to run.  All I need to do now is knit the program.  How do I save my data that I have imported through R studio so that I can call it in my program and knit?

I have tried `save()`, `save.image()`, knitting directly using code that supposedly should have knitted using what was in the environment, and importing data directly using code(this left me with even more problems so I gave up).

This is my latest effort:

```
dir()

[1] "airline.Rdata"       "airline.Rds"         "cheesedata.Rdata"
[4] "cheesedata.Rds"      "desktop.ini"         "myEnvironment.RData"

load('cheesedata.Rds')

load('airline.Rds')
```

The rest of the code should be fine

> Quitting from lines 3-47 (HW3.spin.Rmd)
> Error in readChar(con, 5L, useBytes = TRUE) : cannot open the connection
> Calls:  ... withCallingHandlers -> withVisible -> eval -> eval -> load -> readChar
> Execution halted

Comment: readRDS('cheesedata.Rds') instead of load()?

Comment: I gave that a try and got the same error code.  Is there anything else completely different that error could mean?  I think I might be troubleshooting something that isn't the problem but have no idea what other code to upload that could be the problem.

Comment: Maybe take a look at the best voted answer in this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26994958/error-cannot-open-the-connection-in-executing-knit-html-in-rstudio

Comment: Otherwise, you probably need to provide a more reproducible code example, that we can help you.